# Specify Collection dependency for Molecule

Tags: ansible, molecule

Molecule is informed to download role dependencies from Ansible Galaxy via

```
dependency:
  name: galaxy
  options:
    role-file: requirements.yml
```

However, there doesn't appear to be any documentation on how Molecule can be informed to download Collections. https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#ansible-galaxy does not list a collections option and I don't see an open feature request on https://github.com/ansible/molecule for this.

Asking here in case this is a solved issue for Molecule, otherwise I suppose this would be a feature request on the Molecule github repo. How can I inform Molecule that it needs to download a Collection for a ansible-galaxy dependency?

My `requirements.yml` file looks like this:

```
---

roles:
- src: gantsign.visual-studio-code
- src: artis3n.bitwarden_app

collections:
 - name: artis3n.github
```

This format is supported by Ansible at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/collections_using.html#install-multiple-collections-with-a-requirements-file.

Comment: I was about to tell your there is an [open ticket on the subject on github](https://github.com/ansible/molecule/issues/2466)... until I found out you are the author ;) Good job by the way. That might still benefit other readers which can thumb-up the issue.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me I needed to update my stack exchange username!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I filed against Molecule has been completed, so this functionality is now present in Molecule as of version 3.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#ansible-galaxy) now covers collections as well since [#2609](https://github.com/ansible-community/molecule/pull/2609). However, if you look at this pull request you can see it shouldn't have passed because the tests fail. It makes sense now that I was unable to get a working solution on my host more than 8 days ago; I notice the last merge after tests passed was 8 days ago.

I don't think this latest merge has been released yet, but I believe there is a [workaround](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2019/how-add-integration-tests-ansible-collection-molecule).